# How to add time dimension when concatenating daily TRMM netCDF files using NCO?

Tags: netcdf, netcdf4, nco

I downloaded daily TRMM 3B42 data for a few days from https://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/datasets. The filenames are of the form `3B42_Daily.yyyymmdd.7.nc4.nc4` but the files do not contain any time dimension. Hence when I use `ncecat` to concatenate various files, the date information is missing in the resulting file. I want to know how to add the time information in the combined dataset.

It seems that the timestamp is a part of the global attributes. Here is the relevant part from `ncdump`:

```
$ ncdump -h ~/Downloads/3B42_Daily.19980730.7.nc4.nc4 
netcdf \3B42_Daily.19980730.7.nc4 {
dimensions:
    lon = 201 ;
    lat = 201 ;
variables:
    float lon(lon) ;
...trimmed...
// global attributes:
        :BeginDate = "1998-07-30" ;
        :BeginTime = "01:30:00.000Z" ;
        :EndDate = "1998-07-31" ;
        :EndTime = "01:29:59.999Z" ;
...trimmed...
```

When I tried using `ncecat 3B42_Daily.199808??.7.nc4.nc4 /tmp/daily.nc4` it gives

```
$ ncdump -h /tmp/daily.nc
netcdf daily {
dimensions:
    record = UNLIMITED ; // (5 currently)
    lon = 201 ;
    lat = 201 ;
variables:
    float lon(lon) ;
...trimmed...
// global attributes:
        :BeginDate = "1998-08-01" ;
        :BeginTime = "01:30:00.000Z" ;
        :EndDate = "1998-08-02" ;
        :EndTime = "01:29:59.999Z" ;
...trimmed...
```

The time information in the global attribute of the first file is retained, which is not very useful.

When trying to use `xarray` in python, I face the same issue - again, I could not find how the time information that is contained in the global attribute can be used when concatenating the data.

I can think of two possible solutions, but I do not know how to achieve them.

1. Add timestamp "by hand" using some command to each of the file first, and then use `ncecat`
2. Somehow `ncecat` may read the global attribute and convert it into a dimension and a variable while concatenating.

From the documentation on http://nco.sourceforge.net/nco.html I could not figure out how to achieve either of these two ways. Or is there a third better way to achieve this (concatenation with relevant time information added)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the data files do not follow CF conventions, you will likely have to manually create a time coordinate after using `ncecat` to concatenate the files. It only takes a few commands if the times are regular, e.g.,

```
ncecat -u time in*.nc out.nc
ncap2 -O -s 'time[time]={0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0}' out.nc out.nc
ncatted -a units,time,o,c,"days since 1998-08-01" out.nc
```

or use ncap2's array facilities for generic arithmetic arrays.

Comment: Thanks a lot - that worked perfectly fine if I used the commands in the order `ncecat` followed by `ncap2` followed by `ncatted`. (If you change the order in the answer, it may help others.)

Comment: I forgot to mention that `ncap2` also needed the option `-O` for overwriting the same file. So the command I used was something like `ncap2 -O -s 'time[time]=array(5844,1,$time)' out.nc out.nc`